# ASP.NET WEB API works fine in IIS 7 y IIS7.5, but have a fixed delay in IIS 8.5

Tags: .net, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, iis-7.5, iis-8.5

i have a simple webapi. It only makes a getasync call to a third party WS(in the code i put a dummy WS that you can try).

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<string>> DemoStack()
{
    List<string> nros = new List<string>();

    nros.Add("1");
    nros.Add("2");
    nros.Add("3");
    nros.Add("4");
    nros.Add("5");

    List<string> request = new List<string>();
    foreach (string nro in nros)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;

            string path = string.Format("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{0}", nro);
            string startdate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            string rta;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                rta = "OK" + response.ReasonPhrase;
            }
            else
            {
                rta = "Error" + response.ReasonPhrase;
            }
            string enddate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            request.Add(string.Format("GET:{0}, Start:{1}, End:{2}, Rta:{3}", path, startdate, enddate, rta));
        }
    }

    return request;
}
```

I added the line

> client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;

to just avoid timeout in IIS 8.5 with my real WS.

Answer of this webapi from an IIS 7 and 7.5

```
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<string>
GET:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1, Start:24/11/2016 07:17:40 p.m., End:24/11/2016 07:17:40 p.m., Rta:OKOK
</string>
<string>
GET:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2, Start:24/11/2016 07:17:40 p.m., End:24/11/2016 07:17:40 p.m., Rta:OKOK
</string>
<string>
GET:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3, Start:24/11/2016 07:17:40 p.m., End:24/11/2016 07:17:41 p.m., Rta:OKOK
</string>
<string>
GET:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/4, Start:24/11/2016 07:17:41 p.m., End:24/11/2016 07:17:41 p.m., Rta:OKOK
</string>
<string>
GET:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/5, Start:24/11/2016 07:17:41 p.m., End:24/11/2016 07:17:41 p.m., Rta:OKOK
</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

Answer of this WebApi from an IIS8.5:

```
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<string>
GET:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1, Start:24/11/2016 19:21:34, End:24/11/2016 19:21:35, Rta:OKOK
</string>
<string>
GET:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2, Start:24/11/2016 19:21:35, End:24/11/2016 19:21:50, Rta:OKOK
</string>
<string>
GET:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3, Start:24/11/2016 19:21:50, End:24/11/2016 19:22:05, Rta:OKOK
</string>
<string>
GET:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/4, Start:24/11/2016 19:22:05, End:24/11/2016 19:22:20, Rta:OKOK
</string>
<string>
GET:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/5, Start:24/11/2016 19:22:20, End:24/11/2016 19:22:35, Rta:OKOK
</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

As you can see, using this dummy WS the WEBAPI i have a delay of 15 seconds between calls in IIS8.5, but in IIS7.5 is just 1 second.

With my real WS, the delay between calls is 5 minutes and in IIS 7.5 the difference between start and enddate is just 1 second too.

Comment: Use Fiddler to capture network packets, http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp and also add logging points in your code to print out the time stamps. Then you probably can know where the 15 seconds go, and locate the culprit.

Comment: Hi. I try with fiddler, i capture the webapi request and response, but i cant see any problem. I check all the tabs in the inspector, but I am not an fiddler expert. Can you tell me where should i see to detect some problem?
And the logging points are after and before every Webapi call. Where do you recommend to add more logging points?
Thanks.

Comment: think carefully if you are executing the code in your mind line by line, which lines take the longest? Then modify your code to print out time stamps between lines, to a temp file or any other suitable collector. And with Fiddler captured packets, you can draw a timeline on each of the lines, as well as the main packers on the wire. From that final drawing it should be obvious where the time goes and who is to blame. If you are not quite convenient to carry out the steps, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: The lines which takes long is the get request:
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
The timestamps are after and before that line, there are not other code between them.
I saw in fiddler the info, but of the parent webapi call (not every child ws request). Anyway, i ask microsoft too.
https://forums.iis.net/t/1234628.aspx?ASP+NET+WEB+API+works+fine+in+IIS+7+and+IIS7+5+but+have+a+fixed+delay+in+IIS+8+5
Thanks.